# Reddit clone with rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I've built the basics already for the app. There is a link model and links controller.

The schema for links has the following: "title", "url", "points"

simple.

Now i'm trying to figure out how to increase the points of the link when a user clicks on a "vote" link in the index view loop.

I tried placing the following in the controller:

```
def modify_points
  @link = Link.find(params[:id])
  @link.points += 1
  @link.save
end
```

and in the routes I added the following line:

```
put 'links/:id/vote' => 'links#modify_points'
```

When I type rake routes in terminal it wont properly give the link a name.

How would I go about doing this?

Extra brownie points if include the ajax way :)

Answer (score 2):

You can name the route like this:

```
put 'links/:id/vote' => 'links#modify_points', :as => 'modify_points'
```

Use `:remote => true` in `link_to` options to submit it by AJAX.

Comment: I get No route matches {:controller=>"links", :action=>"modify_points"} missing required keys: [:id]

Comment: Well you have to specify the link id, for example ```modify_points_path(@link.id)```

Comment: It dosent seem to increase the points. I permitted :points in the strong params in the controller. Could my modify_points method be wrong?

Comment: It seems to be. And it is if ```set_link``` is a method that finds the link.

Comment: I updated the method. Still dosent work. Look at original question.

Comment: Ya. ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/links/1/vote"):

Comment: This is my route. put 'links/:id/vote' => 'links#modify_points', :as => 'modify_points'

Comment: So there you go. You are using the GET method but your routes say PUT, add ```:method => :put``` to the ```link_to``` options.

Comment: Silly me. It works now. But I still have to refresh the page to see the changes.